# Searching for annotations in a map

Tags: ios, search, filter, annotations, mkmapview

I wonder if anyone know if it's possible to have a search function in a mapview? 
I want to be able to search/filter annotations with a UISearchbar, just like it's done in the tableview UI. The annotations are loaded from a plist. 
Would be happy for any hints or help, been searching all over and I can't find anything...

Comment: Well what you could do is search the array of items loaded from the plist. Then just plot the found items on the `MKMapView`, zoom in to only show the annotations that are on the map.

Answer (score 1):

Filter them by name with a predicate. eg:

```
NSArray *filteredAnnotations = [self.mapView.annotations filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name beginswith[dc] %@",userInput]];
```

Then remove all, and reload the map using the annotations from the filtered array.

```
[self.mapView removeAnnotations:self.mapView];
self.mapView.annotations = filteredAnnotations;
```

Trigger this code from the method `searchBarTextDidEndEditing:` in the delegate of the `UISearchBar`. Use the UISearchBar without the UISearchBarDisplayController if you don't want a table preview of the search.

Or as rckoenes said, zoom on the region of the filtered annotations. There is probably code for that in SO.